# With TypeScript, how do I enforce a class implements the right function spec?

Tags: typescript, interface

The following bit of TypeScript compiles without error:

```
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
}
interface IVehicle {
    model?: string;
}
interface IClass {
    doSomething(person:IPerson): string;
}

class MyClass implements IClass {
    doSomething(car:IVehicle):string {
        return car.model;
    }
}
```

but I want it to raise an error because `MyClass.doSomething` accepts an `IVehicle` but it should instead accept an `IPerson`.  How do I make the compiler enforce that the class's method accepts the right type of arguments?

Comment: Here is an issue about it https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7485

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7485 as mentioned by niba in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could tell you *why* this is happening because it does seem odd that you're not getting an error that looks like this:

```
index.ts(11,14): error TS2420: Class 'MyClass' incorrectly implements interface 'IClass'.
  Types of property 'doSomething' are incompatible.
    Type '(car: IVehicle) => string' is not assignable to type '(person: IPerson) => string'.
      Types of parameters 'car' and 'person' are incompatible.
        Type 'IPerson' is not assignable to type 'IVehicle'.
          Property 'model' is missing in type 'IPerson'.
```

You'll get the error I pasted above if you turn:

```
interface IVehicle {
    model?: string;
}
```

into:

```
interface IVehicle {
    model: string;
}
```

But I'm with you, I would also expect that error regardless of the optional property in `IVehicle`. Hopefully someone more familiar with the internals of the compiler can tell us why.